# Как найти недостающую или лишнюю скобку, фигурную скобку или точку запятой

Tags: javascript, jquery, sublime-text-3

Всем привет.
не могу найти лишнюю или недостающие () {} ;
редактор sublime text 3, в браузере в консоли не отображается

Comment: https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter/branches